# django-tables2 'module' object has no attribute 'LinkColumn'

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-tables2

I have this problem when using django-tables2 and a custom template rendering.
The issue arises when I added another column, one that is not specified in the model, and the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LinkColumn'` pops up.
The table and the custom rendering worked when just the model columns where used.

Comment: Could you add some code? Where and how are you adding `LinkColumn`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Alex but a figured out.
I wrongly imported tables from django-tables2 instead of creating an alias as it should be done.


I used this: `from django-tables2 import tables`

When it is suposed to be: `import django-tables2 as tables`

Thanks to dyve and bradleyayers whom cryptically answered this question in this thread https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/79

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tables.columns.LinkColumn` instead of `tables.LinkColumn`.
I solved my problem this way.